# How do I keep the aspect ratio of a percentage based clipping path?

Tags: css

I have a triangle with a background image that's clipped using clip-mask. It's percentage based so that it it doesn't look too small/large on different screens.

However I want the triangle to keep it's ratio as screen width/height is changed.

```
.upper-poly {
    position: absolute;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50% 100%, 100% 0);
    background:                url(http://25.media.tumblr.com/fe6e34ef00254f2bd05451f525b02324/tumblr_mw8osqc77F1qdrz3yo3_500.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Here is a fiddle of what I have - out of ideas on how to make this work...

http://jsfiddle.net/HrNC6/3/

Comment: In my opinion, to achieve that, you should not use percentage but px for width and height in your .upper-poly class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One posible solution is this one:

```
.upper-poly {
    position: absolute;
    width: 80%;
    height: 0%;
    padding-bottom: 80%;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50% 100%, 100% 0);
    background:             url(http://25.media.tumblr.com/fe6e34ef00254f2bd05451f525b02324/tumblr_mw8osqc77F1qdrz3yo3_500.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

If the window aspect ratio is too wide, however, the triangle will be cut.

This works because vertical padding expressed as percentage is calculated on the parent width and not height.